# Loading a JDBC driver

Tags: java, jdbc

So I have the following code:

```
@ServiceProvider(service=org.test.Driver.class)
public class TestLDriver implements SQLDriver{
```

and the JDBC layout is:

[image]

Two problems occured, one is.. am I doing the right thing?
The second is that I get an error that this class is not assignable to org.netezza.Driver.class. What am I doing wrong?

When I try to use the

`Class.register(Driver.class)` it gives me a cannot find symbol error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load the Driver class like this:

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.netezza.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    String msg = "Driver is missing\n" +
            "install and rerun the application";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, msg, this.getTitle(), JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    System.exit(1);
}
```

There is no Class.register.

Comment: where should I put this try and catch block in my class?

Comment: You should put it at the start of your application. After it runs correctly, your JDBC-Driver is available. Next step would be to start a Connection and a Statement in order to get your ResultSet.

Comment: what if my format of the url is jdbc:test://<host>/<database>;user=<username>;password=<password>; 
loglevel=<log level>;logdirpath=<log directory>, how would I set the loglevel and logdirpath in this method?

Comment: This is a getConnection example for MySQL: con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://" +
                            appSettings.getMySQLHost() + ":" +
                            appSettings.getMySQLPort() + "/" +
                            appSettings.getMySQLDB() +
                            "?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8",
                    appSettings.getMySQLUser(), appSettings.getMySQLPass()
            );

Comment: Check Netezza manual. The parameters pass in a similar manner. I hope this helps.